# Firebird- Select specific word from string of words

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a String of words/address ..

```
 ID | ADDRESS 
 1   barangay1, City Province
 2   barangay2, City Province
```

what i want to do is to select only the barangay without City and province

```
 ID | ADDRESS
 1   barangay1
 2   barangay2
```

I tried using Position() but it only returns integer .. Can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [POSITION()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-position.html) function you need the [SUBSTRING()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-substring.html) function to extract the part of the string. If the string you're intrested in is from the start of the string till the first comma then

```
select SUBSTRING(ADDRESS from 1 for POSITION(',' in ADDRESS)-1) from T
```

should work. You also might want to run the result throught [TRIM()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-trim.html) function to get rid of any leading and/or trailing whitespace.

Comment: when this formula would be given a string having no single comma - that would be a little LOL